# Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member 'text'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code from the Apple developer website. I followed their steps but my code creates an error.
Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

Teh error I get is:

> Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member 'text'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Mark: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UIStackView!

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }
}
```

Comment: A stack view doesn't have a `text` property. Given the name, `mealNameLabel` should be a label, not a stack view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: so I have a new problem. When using "mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text" I am expecting to see that taken effect when I run the simulator. But the simulator still has the initial value I have given it. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Please, ask a new question for a new problem, however be sure that you have connected the IBAction and the IBOutlets on the storyboard, then try to click the button..

Comment: I have connected them I posted the new question below.

Answer (score -1):

I presume that you have a label `UITextField`, a `UILabel`, and `UIButton` in your storyboard. And you want to change the text in the `mealNameLabel` label when the button is tapped. So you should change the type of `mealNameLabel` from `UIStackView!` to `UILabel`, since a `UIStackView` doesn't have a `text` property.

If you'd like to set the text in the label programmatically when the view loads then do so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mealNameLabel.text = "Put here the text you want"
}
```

`"Put here the text you want"` is just a sample `String`, it could be `nameTextField.text` if you want.

Comment: I did but it is creating another error and doesn't even compile: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What did you do? the code snippet in your comment is incomplete

Comment: I posted the code below. the error I receive is this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Option

Comment: @Sara Are you sure that `mealNameLabel` is a UILabel in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes it is UILabel in the storyboard

Comment: The error means one thing only: `mealNameLabel` is nil, so you should redo the IBOutlet connections